# How to handle API calls in cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

I am looking for a solution in which my code should wait for a rest call if it happens else it should move further and perform the action I need.

```
cy.intercept("<url1>").as("restCall");
cy.intercept("<url2>").as("restCall2");

cy.get("element").each($el) => {
  if ($el.text() === text){
    cy.wrap($el).click();
// here I need a code where if call happens then I will wait for that call to complete
 else{
    ($el.text() === text)
    cy.wrap($el).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cy.wait()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait) to wait on intercepts to complete.

```js
cy.intercept("/foo").as("restCall"); 
cy.intercept("/bar").as("restCall2");
cy.get("element").each($el) => {
  if ($el.text() === text){
    cy.wrap($el).click();
    cy.wait('@restCall');
    cy.wait('@restCall2');
    // code to execute after restCall and restCall2 are completed
  } else { ... }
});
```

If you need to conditionally continue based on if the call occurs, [this question has some of those answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77781744/11625850)